# How to make "xsd:double" show without exponent?

Tags: java, xsd

Our java class is generated from .xsd.

I want to format "xsd:double" without exponent, e.g., I want "111111196.14" rather than "1.1111119614E8".

I want to use "expPresent", refering the following link: Objective Systems - [XML Numeric Values Format Specification](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/xbv15/UsersGuide/XBinder60.html)

But `expPresent` is regarded as invalid content, what could I do?

```
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:expPresent value="false"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I hope "expPresent" could be valid, or use other xsd settings to hide exponent.

Any ideas?